# CakePHP validator Call to a member function setRules() on a non-object

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, model, forgot-password

I'm working in CakePHP 2 and I have been trying to use dynamic validation, because I need different rules for when I have a user register an account (username and email are both required), but when a user fills out a forgot password form, username or email are required but you're not allowed to fill out both username and email.

I call `$this->User->setValidationRules($this->request->params['action'])` in `beforeFilter` from the `UsersController`.

then in the `User` Model class, I have this function:

```
 public function setValidationRules($action) {
    if ($action == 'forgotten_password') {
        $this->validator()->getField('username')->setRules($this->validationSets['forgottenPassword']);
        $this->validator()->getField('email')->setRules($this->validationSets['forgottenPassword']['email']);
    } else {
        $this->validator()->getField('username')->setRules($this->validationSets['default']);
        $this->validator()->getField('email')->setRules($this->validationSets['default']['email']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

But I keep getting this error: "Call to a member function setRules() on a non-object."

I have been trying to figure this out for so long. In the `AppModel` class, I added the line:

```
App::Uses(Validator, Model);
```

But I still get the same error.

I have been trying to figure this out for a long time, searching all over the internet for answers, but I can't seem to find any. If anyone could help. I would much appreciate it.

Comment: I also just tried changing App::Uses(Validator, Model) to App::Uses(ModelValidator, Model) in the AppModel class, but I still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->validator()->getField('field')` can return `null` if your fields are not defined in the model.

Can you please post the entire model definition and also the controller function where you call `setValidationRules`? (Is this the controller that has the same name as the model or is a different controller?)

With what you have posted so far, it seems like you're calling the `Validator` methods before the validator has been properly set up. This indicates either a typo in the field names (unlikely), a model that was not properly initialized or the call to `setValidationRules` happens before the Model was fully build. I'd make sure that the controller is the only one calling that function.

You can always dump the values of:

- `$this->validator()`
- `$this->validator()->getField('field')`
- `$this->validator()->getField(null)` - to get a list of all the available fields in the validator and possibly an indication of the problem.

And you can have a look at the stack trace of the call to `setValidationRules()` to make sure it happens when you think it should happen.

If more data is posted in the question I'll be able to refine my answer.